# Calculate absolute value of numbers using Generic class

Tags: c#, .net, generics

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AbsValue<int> ABS = new AbsValue<int>();
    AbsValue<double> ABSdouble = new AbsValue<double>();

        ABS.X = -5;
        ABSdouble.X = 65.3;

    Console.WriteLine("Integer absolute value: {0}", Math.Abs(ABS.X));
    Console.WriteLine("Double absolute value: {0}", Math.Abs(ABSdouble.X));

    Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

I don't think that it is correctly, but it seems to work. Can you please give me some advise, how i can make it better?

```
class AbsValue<T>
{ 
     public T X;  
}
```

Comment: Nope, thats pretty much it. What do you think is wrong with that approach of getting the absolute value?

Comment: You should include your call to `Math.Abs` inside the `AbsValue` class.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez How?  `Math.Abs` isn't generic.

Comment: @DStanley, using GetType, maybe? I understand it defeats the purpose of generics, but if you want an `AbsValue` class, you can't let it have an invalid value (in this case, a negative).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a clean way to wrap `Math.Abs` into a generic function, because 1) the function is not generic but instead designed with [overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.abs(v=vs.110).aspx) for each numeric type, and 2) creating a generic restraint for numeric types is not possible in .NET<sup>1</sup>.

Even if you did that you'd still have to have a giant `switch` statement to call the proper `Math.Abs` overload.

I think I'd find a different problem to solve as a beginner - this one is not an easy learning exercise.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>You can get close by constraining the parameter to `struct, IComparable, IFormattable`, but it doesn't really buy you much as you'd have to cast to use any operators or framework math functions.</sub>

Comment: `string` does not satisfy the `struct` constraint.

Comment: @Servy Thanks - temporary insanity, I was thinking value type.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do `Abs` generically you can create an interface and implement it for `double` and `int` e.g.:

```
public interface IAbsNum<T>
{
   T Abs(T num);
}

public class IntAbsNum : IAbsNum<int>
{
    public int Abs(int num) { return Math.Abs(num); }
}
```